# Using srcElement in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I have a problem in Firefox. I can't use `window.event.srcElement.id` in Firefox and flow code doesn't work in Firefox. Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("img[rel]").overlay(function() {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var sid = window.event.srcElement.id;
                document.getElementById("SelectedNewsID").value = sid;
            }
            else {
                //alert("Error.");
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do vanilla JavaScript when you've already taken the hit for including jQuery? Use jQuery if you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("img[rel]").click(function(e){
       $("#SelectedNewsID").val(e.target.id);
    }).overlay();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

window.event.srcElement works only in IE. For all other browsers window.event does not work. If you are using JQuery to bind the click event or any other event you will get the event object in which event.target will give you the target element.

Comment: can you help me and write a sample? please

Comment: Are you getting any event object in the overlay callback function? If yest then use that instead of looking for window.event.

Comment: i write like this for firefox    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("img[rel]").overlay(function(e) {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var sid = window.event.srcElement.id;
                document.getElementById("SelectedNewsID").value = sid;
            }
            else { var sid = e.target.id; (and e.target.getatribute("id");
                document.getElementById("SelectedNewsID").value = sid;

                //alert("Error.");
            }...

Comment: Are you getting anything in e parameter? You can also look at my other answer hope that helps.